# Which is the Fastest method to check Rows existence while fetching?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

From the following Queries, Which one is the most optimal and fastest to use?

`[COUNT(id)]`

```
$SQL = "SELECT name, COUNT(id) as Count FROM names WHERE name = :name";
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($data['count'] > 0) {
    while ($row) {
        $name = $row['name'];
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

OR `[rowCount()]`

```
$SQL = "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name = :name";
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $name = $row['name'];
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

OR `[EXISTS]`

```
$SQLEX = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM names WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1)";
if ($stmt->fetchColumn == 1) {
    $SQL = "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name = :name";
    while (row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $name = $row['name'];
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

OR `[RAW]`

```
$SQL = "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name = :name";
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    while($row) {
        $name = $row['name'];
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

Also i wanted to know, Why does using `$stmt->fetch()` with `$stmt->rowCount()` allows me to fetch data, But using it with `$stmt->fetchColumn` doesn't?

Comment: They all do slightly different things so asking which is most optimal or fastest is not valid. Besides which, as they each return a single row, *optimal or fastest* is practically irrelevant.

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM names WHERE name = :name` ... why bother even selecting the `name` if you're only concerned with its existence. In real terms though this is all pretty academic. Since this is PDO you should *only* use `rowCount` with INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE queries *not* SELECT.

Comment: @CD001 The problem is that In one query i want to check if row exists or not, If it exists, I define and use it.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. From the code it is apparent that you need not only to check but to fetch as well. that's a different story.

Comment: why did you add a completely pointless while to your examples?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Will fix the title right now, I added while() to fetch all the rows, after checking if rows exists

Comment: So there are multiple rows possible and you need them all? What a plot twist.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sorry about the mistaken title i wrote previous if it made a big different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems this question needs more than one answer...

f you need to check the existence only,

- if there is an **unique index** for the field, all methods are equal, but some of them just make no sense.
- if there is no unique index, then go for EXISTS

If you need to fetch the actual data and see if there was anything returned, then just select your data and fetch it:

- if only one column from a single row is expected, then use fetchColumn()
- if only one row is expected, then use fetch()
- if multiple rows are expected, then use fetchAll()

and then use the resulting value to see whether your query returned any data.

So if you finally made your mind as to what you're asking about, here is the most optimal code for you:

```
$SQL = "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name = :name";
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
if (!$data) {
    return;
}
foreach ($data as $name) ...
```

And there is nothing wrong with fetchColumn() other than your idea to use it.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you have an index on `names(name)`, then all should be quite comparable in speed.

Second, it is always worth trying such performance tests on your own system.

Third, if names are declared as unique (or primary key) in the `names` table, then all should be quite fast.

In general, though, the fastest way to determine if a row is available is:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM names WHERE name = :name)
```

The `LIMIT 1` in the subquery is unnecessary -- `EXISTS` stops at the first row (whether the database uses an index or a table scan).

In general, the first method using an aggregation is the worst solution.  Without an index, it is going to result in a full table scan that reads the entire table.  The second might or might not read the entire table, depending on whether the database starts returning matching rows as they are available.  It also has the downside of returning more data.

Comment: It's a common misconception. If your query relies on whatever limiter, be it EXISTS or LIMIT, then it's non-optimal by design.

Comment: @YourCommonSense . . . That is so far from reality that I find it hard to believe that anyone would believe that.  Interesting.  But human-kind has and still has all sorts of absurd beliefs.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that in this particular case an unique index should be used. but realized it is not always the case.

Comment: in the `Second` one, I always find it as you said, Gives false row numbers, Even in empty table it gave me sometimes the value `1`, The most accurate one was using `fetchColumn()` But it prevents me from using `fetch()` after it, Why is that?

Comment: @Toleo because you 1) Didn't select anything sensible and 2) ALREADY fetched that.